# Use LINQ to populate a single list from two other lists without duplicates

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I have 2 lists :-

```
OrigFruitList.Add(new Fruit { Category = "Apple", SubCategory = "" });
        OrigFruitList.Add(new Fruit { Category = "Apple", SubCategory = "Red Apple" });
        OrigFruitList.Add(new Fruit { Category = "Apple", SubCategory = "Green Apple" });
        OrigFruitList.Add(new Fruit { Category = "Orange", SubCategory = "" });
        OrigFruitList.Add(new Fruit { Category = "Peach", SubCategory = "" });
        OrigFruitList.Add(new Fruit { Category = "Grapes", SubCategory = "Green Grapes" });
        OrigFruitList.Add(new Fruit { Category = "Grapes", SubCategory = "Black Grapes" });
        OrigFruitList.Add(new Fruit { Category = "Bananas", SubCategory = "" });

        NormalFruitList.Add(new Fruit { Category = "Apple", SubCategory = "" });
        NormalFruitList.Add(new Fruit { Category = "Apple", SubCategory = "Red Apple" });
        NormalFruitList.Add(new Fruit { Category = "Apple", SubCategory = "Green Apple" });
        NormalFruitList.Add(new Fruit { Category = "Orange", SubCategory = "Blood Orange" });
        NormalFruitList.Add(new Fruit { Category = "Orange", SubCategory = "Sweet Orange" });
        NormalFruitList.Add(new Fruit { Category = "Peach", SubCategory = "" });
        NormalFruitList.Add(new Fruit { Category = "Bananas", SubCategory = "" });
        NormalFruitList.Add(new Fruit { Category = "Bananas", SubCategory = "Yellow Bananas" });
        NormalFruitList.Add(new Fruit { Category = "Bananas", SubCategory = "Green Bananas" });
```

Now I wish to merge the second list, with LINQ if possible, depending on the first list.

For example there is only 1 entry for Orange in the Original List, and I wish to append the 2 entries from the Normal list to the Original list.  Same goes for Bananas.

How can I achieve that with LINQ?

Thanks for your help and time

------------RESULT I wish to achieve

```
//FinalResult
        //Apple
        //Red Apple
        //Green Apple
        //Orange
        //Blood Orange
        //Sweet Orange
        //Peach
        //Green Grapes
        //Black Grapes
        //Bananas
        //Yellow Banans
        //Green Bananas
```

Comment: And when is a duplicate a duplicate? And what is the Shape of the desired result?

Comment: Henk I added the Final Desired list to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        var difference = NormalFruitList.Where(normFruit =>
            !OrigFruitList.Exists(
                origFruit => origFruit.Category == normFruit.Category 
                    && origFruit.SubCategory == normFruit.SubCategory));

        // If new Category is found in NormalFruitList it will be added to the end
        int index = 0;
        var result = new List<Fruit>(OrigFruitList);
        foreach (var item in difference.Reverse())
        {
            index = result.IndexOf(OrigFruitList.FirstOrDefault(fruit => fruit.Category == item.Category));
            result.Insert(index == -1 ? OrigFruitList.Count : index + 1, item);
        }
```

Comment: Ivan, thanks for solution but its not in the order I would like it to be

Comment: please look at my updated question.  Basically I want to keep the order in the Original list, and append the differences from the Normal list

Comment: Ok that almost works, however the order in the second list for the SubCategories is not kept, for example getting "Sweet Orange" before "Blood Orange" and "Green Bananas" before "Yellow Bananas"

Comment: Also if possible, everything needs to be appended to the NormalList as a final List

Comment: Perfect Ivan, I just need to append the items to the NormalList instead of the Original, is there a better way then just doing a normal insert?

Comment: I believe it's OK now, result is saved in a new list called `result`, source lists remain same.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mrgList = OrigFruitList
    .Union(NormalFruitList)
    .GroupBy(n => new {n.Category, n.SubCategory}, (fruit, fruits) => fruits.First());
```

Comment: can you give me an example?  I already tried a join but did not work

Comment: Malmi I like your solution, but I need to keep the same order in list 1.  At the moment you are concatinating the difference of the lists at the end of the list. Please see updated question on the result I wish to achieve

Answer (score 0):

If Fruit is struct so:

```
var result = OrigFruitList.Union(NormalFruitList);
```

If Fruit is class so:

```
var resul=new List<Fruit>();
foreach(var fruit in NormalFruitList)
{
    var item = OrigFruitList.firstOrDefault(p=>p.Category == fruit.Category 
                             && p.SubCategory == fruit.SubCategory));
   if(item!=null)
       resul.Add(item);
}
NormalFruitList.AddRange(result);
```

Comment: Hi Reza this is not working properly, getting lots of duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a fruit is a duplicate when there's another fruit with the same `Category` **and** `SubCategory`, you can use [`Enumerable.Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407.aspx) with a custom [`IEqualityComparer<Fruit>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx):

```
class Fruit
{
    public String Category { get; set; }
    public String SubCategory { get; set; }

    public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Fruit>
    {
        public bool Equals(Fruit x, Fruit y)
        {
            return y.Category == y.Category && x.SubCategory == y.SubCategory;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Fruit obj)
        {
            return (obj.Category + obj.SubCategory).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use the comparer in `Union`:

```
OrigFruitList = OrigFruitList
                .Union(NormalFruitList, new Fruit.Comparer())
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = OrigFruitList.Union(NormalFruitList,new FruitComparer())

public class FruitComparer : IEqualityComparer<Fruit>
{       

  public bool Equals(Fruit x, Fruit y)
  {
      return y.Category == y.Category && x.SubCategory == y.SubCategory;
  }

  public int GetHashCode(Fruit f)
  {
    return (f.Category + f.SubCategory).GetHashCode();
  }

}
```